# Mongo's aggregate command underutilizes CPU(s)

Tags: mongodb, performance, aggregation-framework

I have Mongo 2.2.2 running on Windows 7 x64 on i7 eight-core CPU. Our production servers are running under Red Hat Enterprise on 256-core machines with same version of Mongo.

In my tests of following call on my Windows machine

```
db.users_v2_prod.aggregate( { $group : {_id : "$email", total : { $sum : 1 } } }, { $match : { total : { $gte : 3 } } }, { $sort : {total : -1} }, {$limit : 5} )
```

I noticed that mongo underutilizes available resources. During the query total load on CPU is ~10%. According to Process Explorer computation occurs only in one thread. `mongod` seems to be using only 3 cores out of 8 I have and even they're used partially.

Could Mongo's engineers please explain their rationale to this implementation ? I'm curious why not use more resources if they are available. Why not parallel the load across all cores since you have index for a field I'm grouping at.

Given query was executed on collection with 6.5M documents (mongobackup produces 5GB file). So it's nothing crazy.

PS. And bonus question: have you thought about using GPU ? I have 1024-cores GPU on my laptop :)

Comment: Why do you assume this is CPU bound? MapReduce and other plain JavaScript stuff like ``eval()`` are limited to a single core, but everything else shouldn't be limited to that. Maybe some more details (``iostat``, ``vmstat``,...) would help to get a better idea what's going on. Unfortunately there's no ``explain()`` for aggregate queries yet, but yours should be good - see http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/aggregation/#optimizing-performance

Comment: I am not a MongoDB dev however multithreaded aggregation is somewhere on the JIRA I believe, I can't find it atm cos I suck at searching it however it is there. So there are definitely plans to make the pipe lines much better in future with handling stuff like multi threading and what not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In all likelihood, CPU is not the bounding factor here - that is true most of the time with typical use cases for MongoDB.  Your query does not look computationally intensive, so it's more likely to be hitting a limit in terms of paging data off disk or running out of RAM.

It's hard to say without seeing actual stats for the run (for that I would recommend having the host in [MMS](http://mms.mongodb.com/help-classic/) with [munin-node](http://mms.mongodb.com/help-classic/tutorial/configure-monitoring-munin-node/) installed), but I have rarely seen the CPU be the bottleneck on a MongoDB instance.

Having said all that, the parallelization can probably be improved, but it may not be the quickest thing to get implemented.  If none of the above is happening ore relevant, then I would see if you can run multiple jobs in parallel, or perhaps split up the work more on the client side to see if you can improve matters that way.  You should also probably watch/vote/comment on these issues:

https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5091 (parallelize aggregating operations)
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-5088 (parallel query)
https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-4504 (adding explain for aggregation framework) (added in 2.6)